# What comprises the AIS-31 standard for TRNGs?

Tags: hardware, random

I'm researching how my smart card's chipset generates random numbers. According to a [source in forums](http://forum.yubico.com/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=1874&p=7297#p7297) the YubiKey NEO is based on the A700x chipset from NXP. The [page for the chipset](http://www.nxp.com/products/identification_and_security/authentication/series/A700X_FAMILY.html) indicates that the chipset provides a:

> Low-power True Random Number Generator (TRNG) in hardware, AIS-31 compliant

I've been trying to determine what the AIS-31 spec defines, but Google has been fairly unproductive. I can find other chipsets that are certified by the same standard, but what does the certification mean? How is testing done?

Once I know either a) how this TRNG is implemented or b) what the certification consists of and means, I'll then be able to determine how much trust I should place in this chip's random number generation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

BSI: Application Notes and Interpretation of the Scheme (AIS) 31 – Functionality
Classes and Evaluation Methodology for Physical Random Number Generators,
Version 1 (25.09.2001), English translation.

BSI's AIS site is [here](https://www.bsi.bund.de/SharedDocs/Downloads/DE/BSI/Zertifizierung/Interpretationen/AIS_31_pdf.html).

Standard is [here](https://www.bsi.bund.de/SharedDocs/Downloads/DE/BSI/Zertifizierung/Interpretationen/AIS_20_AIS_31_Evaluation_of_random_number_generators_e.pdf?__blob=publicationFile).

Comment: sorry for link-only, the question is answered with a google search

Answer (score 0):

I think this document should be considered as contemporary AIS31 standard:

[A proposal for: Functionality classes for random number generators. Version 2.0, 18 September 2011](https://cosec.bit.uni-bonn.de/fileadmin/user_upload/teaching/15ss/15ss-taoc/01_AIS31_Functionality_classes_for_random_number_generators.pdf)

Also this document exists (it is much newer, but it is not approved, it is an intermediate version):

[A Proposal for Functionality Classes for Random Number Generators. Version 2.36. 2 June, 2023](https://www.bsi.bund.de/SharedDocs/Downloads/EN/BSI/Certification/Interpretations/AIS_31_Functionality_classes_for_random_number_generators_e_2023.pdf?__blob=publicationFile&v=2)

Comment: It would be far more helpful if you provided a link instead of suggesting that others find the links

Comment: And, these are not the AIS-31 standard. These are tangential, which means these are not what was asked...